# Best replacement for GCC #ident

Tags: gcc, ident

I used to set this at top of my source files to be able to `grep -a "ID :"` on my binaries :

```
#ident "\\n$@           ID : my_library.o v1.3 (25/08/07)@$\\n"
```

However, this is deprecated in GCC 4.3.3. Any suggestions ?

I came through `__attributes__(section())`, but not sure if this will get stripped, and anyway, I was guessing there was a more straightforward way.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The #ident directive (as well as #sccs) was undeprecated, so you should just keep it!

(see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41632)