# How can I conditionally include #ident directives in a macro?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

A bug in gcc-4.4 causes the `#ident` directive to emit a warning.  We don't allow warnings in our compiler (-Werror) so I need to turn these off when compiled on certain GCC compiler versions.  (See [Best replacement for GCC #ident](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650222/best-replacement-for-gcc-ident))

```
$ echo '#ident "FAILS on gcc-4.3.3"' > test.c
$ gcc-4.4 -c test.c
test.c:1: warning: #ident is a deprecated GCC extension
```

Since these occur in several locations I want to replace them with a macro which would conditionally emit either nothing (or something that approximates `#ident`) on those "bad" compilers or with the actual `#ident` directive on all others.  Ideally, something like this:

```
# test2.c
#ifndef HAS_HASH_IDENT
#  define IDENT(x) //-- NO-OP
#else
#  define IDENT(x) #ident x
#endif
```

This doesn't work because the preprocessor chokes on the `#` of `#ident`, as it is interpreted as the stringize operator when used in a macro.

```
$ gcc-4.5 -Wall -E test2.c
test2.c:4:22: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
```

I tried several macro redirection tricks, but nothing I came up with would satisfy the preprocessor.

Is something like this even possible?

---

Note: The `#ident` directive is passed on intact to the compiler by the preprocessor, so the problem I'm having is **not** restricted by some sort of preprocessor recursion limitation.

```
$ gcc-4.5 -E test.c         
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"
#ident "FAILS on gcc-4.3.3"
```

Comment: If you're going to be editing every occurrence of `#ident` anyway, why not just bracket them in `#ifdef`?

Comment: i see you have problems with gcc 4.4, but are using 4.5 aswell. Does this bug still exists? and what sort of bug it is?

Comment: @fazo The bug is that someone marked the #ident directive as deprecated in gcc 4.4.  This was corrected in gcc 4.5, so it is only on machines with gcc 4.4 installed that this is a problem for me.  But I have dozens of developers using this shared code, and I don't want to always have to explain the same solution (install gcc 4.5).  But my question is really about macro-izing the #ident directive.

Comment: You can have your build system make a copy of affected files, remove `#ident` from the copy and compile those instead. Very hacky but should work.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want to use this option

> `-fno-ident`
>        Ignore the `#ident` directive.

maybe this switches off the warning, too.

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work. 
`$ gcc-4.4 -fno-ident -c test.c`
`test.c:1: warning: #ident is a deprecated GCC extension`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selectively muting that specific warning? Something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3125889/2003487